# Приложения на tkinter в exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

При запуске готового `exe` файла, созданного с помощью `pyinstaller`, на доли секунды вылазит окно с консолью и приложение закрывается. Пробовал запускать `pyinstaller` с ключом `-w`, но тогда просто вылезала ошибка.

Comment: Описание никудышное, что и как делал - непонятно, вопроса нет. Какой помощи ты ждешь?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить через cmd

Comment: Также, если запускаете приложение со своими иконками - проверьте лежат ли они в нужный папках или нет

Answer (score 3):

Знакомая проблема, такое же было. Там все дело в том, что не смотря на то, что в `pyinstaller` много ключей и якобы можно ввести те, что вам нужно и все будет работать, это не так.

Вы должны ввести `pyinstaller main.py --onefile --noconsole`.

`main.py` - это ваш основной файл. Когда все соберется закиньте оставшиеся файлы вручную.
Было:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Запустили:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Появится папка dist в которой будет exeшник. Туда закиньте то, что вам нужно из-за зависимостей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще бывает, закрывается из-за того, что у вас ошибка в коде, тогда на доли секунды вылезет окно и сразу закроется. По факту, оно вылезает, там появляется ошибка (на строке такой то синтаксическая ошибка) и сразу закрывается из-за ошибки. Тогда перед созданием exeшника попробуйте запустить код, отладьте ошибки и заново запустите `pyinstaller`.

Comment: На счёт закрытия из-за ошибки - можно запустить exe прямо в консоли. Довольно тупо, но всё же можно)